# How to apply a CellFormat to Cell

Tags: c#, excel, openxml

Here is my code:

```
public MemoryStream ExportDataTableToExcel(DataTable exportData, string sheetTitle = "Exported Data", bool includeColumnHeaders = true) {
    uint excelRow = 1;

    MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream();
    SpreadsheetDocument objSpreadsheet = SpreadsheetDocument.Create(ms, SpreadsheetDocumentType.Workbook);
    WorkbookPart objWorkbookPart = objSpreadsheet.AddWorkbookPart();

    var wsp = objSpreadsheet.WorkbookPart.WorkbookStylesPart;

    if (wsp == null) {
        //objSpreadsheet.WorkbookPart.DeletePart(wsp);
        var stylesPart = objSpreadsheet.WorkbookPart.AddNewPart<WorkbookStylesPart>();
        stylesPart.Stylesheet = new Stylesheet();
        CellFormat cf = new CellFormat {
            NumberFormatId = 14,
            FontId = 0,
            FillId = 0,
            BorderId = 0,
            FormatId = 0,
            ApplyNumberFormat = BooleanValue.FromBoolean(true)
        };
        stylesPart.Stylesheet.CellFormats = new CellFormats();
        stylesPart.Stylesheet.CellFormats.AppendChild<CellFormat>(cf);
        stylesPart.Stylesheet.CellFormats.Count = UInt32Value.FromUInt32((uint)stylesPart.Stylesheet.CellFormats.ChildElements.Count);
        ////ss.Save(stylesPart);
        stylesPart.Stylesheet.Save();
    }

    objWorkbookPart.Workbook = new Workbook();
    WorksheetPart objSheetPart = objWorkbookPart.AddNewPart<WorksheetPart>();
    objSheetPart.Worksheet = new Worksheet(new SheetData());
    Sheets objSheets = objSpreadsheet.WorkbookPart.Workbook.AppendChild<Sheets>(new Sheets());
    Sheet objSheet = new Sheet();

    objSheet.Id = objSpreadsheet.WorkbookPart.GetIdOfPart(objSheetPart);
    objSheet.SheetId = 1;
    objSheet.Name = sheetTitle;
    objSheets.Append(objSheet);


    if (includeColumnHeaders) {
        for (int intCol = 0; intCol < exportData.Columns.Count; intCol++) {
            string excelColumn = this.ConvertIndexToColumnValue(intCol + 1);
            string headerText = Common.TextTransformations.CapitalizeWords(exportData.Columns[intCol].ColumnName.Replace("_", " "));

            Cell objCell = InsertCellInWorksheet(excelColumn, excelRow, objSheetPart);
            objCell.CellValue = new CellValue(headerText);
            objCell.DataType = new EnumValue<CellValues>(CellValues.String);
        }
        excelRow++;
    }

    //Iterate through the row and column and add it to the cell
    foreach(DataRow row in exportData.Rows) {                
        for (int intCol = 0; intCol < exportData.Columns.Count; intCol++) {
            string excelColumn = this.ConvertIndexToColumnValue(intCol + 1);

            Cell objCell = InsertCellInWorksheet(excelColumn, excelRow, objSheetPart);

            if (exportData.Columns[intCol].DataType.ToString().Trim().ToLower() == "system.datetime") {
                objCell.DataType = new EnumValue<CellValues>(CellValues.Number);
                objCell.CellValue = new CellValue(((DateTime)row[intCol]).ToOADate().ToString());
                objCell.StyleIndex = 0;
                //
                //objCell.StyleIndex = 5;
                //objCell.CellReference = "A1";
            }else{
                objCell.CellValue = new CellValue(row[intCol].ToString());
                objCell.DataType = new EnumValue<CellValues>(this.GetCellValueFromColumnType(exportData.Columns[intCol]));

            }

        }

        excelRow++;
    }

    objSheetPart.Worksheet.Save();
    objSpreadsheet.WorkbookPart.Workbook.Save();

    objSpreadsheet.Close();
    return ms;        
}
```

The problem is, after the xlsx is generated, when I try to open it, it said "Microsoft Excel has stopped working". I am sure that the cellformat part of my code is wrong, but I just don't know how to correct it.

Comment: Did you solve the issue ??

Answer (score 3):

The problem is you are not creating the stylesheet properly.

To create the simplest stylesheet you need to include Font, Fill and Border. They are mandatory even you don not use them. And in your code though you have used indexes for FontId, FillId and BorderId you haven't actually define them.

```
        // Where are these coming from ??? 
        FontId = 0,
        FillId = 0,
        BorderId = 0,
```

Said that I provide following code snippet which would create the simplest style sheet ,

```
WorkbookStylesPart stylesheet = spreadsheet.WorkbookPart.AddNewPart<WorkbookStylesPart>();

Stylesheet workbookstylesheet = new Stylesheet();


// <Fonts>
Font font0 = new Font();         // Default font : Id =0

/* An example for another font
Font font1 = new Font();         // Bold font
Bold bold = new Bold();
font1.Append(bold);
*/

Fonts fonts = new Fonts();      // <APENDING Fonts>   
fonts.Append(font0);

//fonts.Append(font1);  // <= Bold font 

// <Fills>
Fill fill0 = new Fill();        // Default fill : Id = 0


Fills fills = new Fills();      // <APENDING Fills>
fills.Append(fill0);

// <Borders>
Border border0 = new Border();     // Defualt border : Id = 0

Borders borders = new Borders();    // <APENDING Borders>
borders.Append(border0);

// <CellFormats> : Now you can simple use above defined ID's
CellFormat cellformat0 = new CellFormat() { FormatId = 0, FillId = 0, BorderId = 0 }; 


// <APENDING CellFormats>
CellFormats cellformats = new CellFormats();
cellformats.Append(cellformat0);


// Append FONTS, FILLS , BORDERS & CellFormats to stylesheet <Preserve the ORDER>
workbookstylesheet.Append(fonts);
workbookstylesheet.Append(fills);
workbookstylesheet.Append(borders);
workbookstylesheet.Append(cellformats);

stylesheet.Stylesheet = workbookstylesheet;
stylesheet.Stylesheet.Save();
```

yes it's bit lengthy, but only one time code you will use forever..